# Gmsh 2D shape with boundaries

Tags: gmsh

I'm trying to generate a mesh which has inlet and outlet boundary conditions at the top (not included in the code below). I need the mesh to be whole, but the issue is the transfinite surface as gmsh is reading the input as 'not a rectangle'. Ideally the whole thing is one surface and a 2D mesh can be generated inside of it, I just can't get around the boundary restrictions I have from this transfinite surface line.

```c
lc = 1e-4;

Point(1) = {-1, 2, 0, lc};
Point(2) = {0, 2, 0, lc};
Point(3) = {1, 2, 0, lc};
Point(4) = {0,-0.8,0,lc};
Point(12) = {-1,0,0,lc};
Point(13) = {1,0,0,lc};
Point(16) = {0,0,0,lc};

Ellipse(5) = {12,16,16,4};
Ellipse(6) = {4,16,16,13};
Line(7) = {3,2};
Line(8) = {2,1};
Line(14) = {1,12};
Line(15) = {3,13};

Line Loop(9) = {6,-15,7, 8,14,5};

Transfinite Line "*" = 50;

Plane Surface (11) = {9};
Transfinite Surface "*";
Recombine Surface "*";

Physical Surface("flowing_layer") = {11};
Physical Line("Bottom_Left") = {5};
Physical Line("Bottom_Right") = {6};
Physical Line("Left") = {14};
Physical Line("Right") = {15};
```

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE. Your question is off-topic on this site, since it is related to how to achieve a particular result in a software.